# Internal css not working in email templates on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile-browser, email-templates

I've been working on email templates. They look great on desktop and gmail app on android/iOS but look ugly if a open gmail in chrome/safari (I've tested on these only). I've added css in my `head` tag but it looks that in mobile browsers only inline css is working. So if i want to show different logos on mobile and desktop they both show in mobile browser.

I've tried moving my css in inside `body` tag as per different questions. Here's [one of the things i've tried](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/889-hide-show-td-in-gmail-outlook-yahoo?fbclid=IwAR2gsBs8OVdVCnWGS_t3R4FQlKgI-W9-W6rHuJczoeoZEDNyN6hy-RS4ebc)! but this doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Sadly, inline CSS is *still* the *only* consistent way of displaying HTML emails correctly.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that.

Comment: CSS in the head (even media query) can be read by Gmail but its strict. Any unwanted space, or syntax error the CSS will be ignored. I answered a question right here on SO where media query works in Gmail. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701247/how-do-i-write-a-media-query-for-gmail/49724395)

Comment: `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)` here's my media query @Syfer and its same as yours

Comment: Perhaps you didn't read my question clearly. Its working on Gmail App. Its just not working in mobile browser gmail

Comment: You right, i didn't read it properly, media queries don't work in gmail when viewed in browser that's why they recommend to use app. Also my media query's not same as yours. Spaces makes a difference when it comes to Gmail.

Comment: you could try dev tools to see why its not working. it will give you an idea.