# How do I code a responsive HTML email without media queries (for Gmail)?

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

I am attempting to code my first HTML email. I have it working and everything looks great until I view it in mobile and then I see a few small tweaks I would like to make. I understand that I must use all inline CSS as Gmail won't recognize the style tag. What I don't understand is how to create code that will handle different screen sizes without using @media screen and (max-width)? Any help would be appreciated as I said I am very new to this. Thanks in advance for your help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--Quite a few clients strip your Doctype out, and some even apply their own. Many clients do honor your doctype and it can make things much easier if you can validate constantly against a Doctype.-->
<html>
    <head></head>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="format detection" content="telephone=no">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=Edge" />
<title>Email template for USA Label Express</title>

<!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
<!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->

<style type="text/css">
    
    /* some resets and issue fixes */
        #outlook a { padding:0; }
        body{ width:100% !important; -webkit-text; size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }     
        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
        .ExternalClass {width:100%;} 
    .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding: 0; width:100%; !important;}
    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
    .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%}
    
    /* End Reset */
    
    /* use to fix table positioning
    td{
        border:thin #000000 solid;
        
    }
    */
    
    /*Display block allows us to stack elements */
    
    *[class="mobile-column"] {display:block;}
    
    /*Some more stacking elements */
    
    *[class="mob-column"] {float: none !important; width: 100% !important;}
    
    /* hide stuff */
    *[class="hide"] {display: none !important;}
    
    /*This sets elements to 100% width and fixes the height issues */
    
    *[class="100p"] {width100% !important; height: auto !important;}
    
    /*for the 2x2 stack */
    
    *[class="condensed"] {padding-bottom: 40px !important; display block;}
    
    /*Centers content on mobile */
    
    *[class="center"] {text-align: center !important; width: 100% !important; height: auto !important;}
/*100percent width section with 20px padding */
    *[class="100pad"] {width: 100% !important; padding: 20px;}
    /*same as above with 20px padding left and right */
    *[class="100padleftright"] {width: 100% !important; padding: 0 20px 0 20px;}
    /*again but top and bottom */
    *[class="100padtopbottom"] {width: 100% !important; padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none!important;
    font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, "sans-serif";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #001588;
    font-size: 11px;
}
    
    table{
        border-spacing: 0px;
    }
    
    
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #email{
        background-image: url("https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/c7552f30-ebb5-ff4f-16aa-ab8921f6145e.jpg");
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-color: #DBDCEF;
        background-size: cover;
        
    }
    
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* Here you can include rules for the Android and iPhone 
    native email clients. 
    
    Device viewport dimensions are as follows
    Iphone - 320px X 480px - portrait, 480px X 320px - landscape
    Android - 350px X 480px - portrait, 480px X 350px - landscape
    (These are average dimensions, the Android OS runs on several different devices)
    */
    
    .address{
        
        font-size: 7px !important;
    }
    
    }
    
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
<div id="email" style="width:600px; height: 220px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; ">

<!-- Top Text --> 
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td> <a href="http://www.usalabelexpress.com/LabelInformation.php?Capabilities-5"> <img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/bf2c9f86-218b-ec7f-c0ad-50543875f454.png
" alt="custom label printing, flexographic, digital, promotional products, small or large run capabilities, in house art dept" style="padding: 5px;" class="topText responsiveImage"></a> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- Body --> 
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr style="border-spacing: 0px;">
    <td width="13%"> 
        <a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/53bab0ac-c3a4-1dcd-a8ff-31d20cf90e92.png"  alt="" height="" width="" style="padding-left: 15px;" class="eagle responsiveImage"></a> 
    </td> 
    <td width="53%"> 
        <a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/52310cc7-b1d1-4dca-63d9-c2718d4e3ac0.png"  alt="" height="" width="" class="logo responsiveImage" ></a> 
    </td>
    <td width="34%" style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">
            
        <a href="https://usalabelexpress.com/Staff.php?Jim-Seldenright-9" style=" padding-left:60%; padding-top: 10%;"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/45f224f6-a3cb-2c49-1c92-0a25eedea4e7.jpg" alt="Jim Seldenright Salesman" height="" width="60px" class="repImage responsiveImage" style="border:1px solid #001588;">Jim Seldenright <br /> Sales Representative </a> 

    </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
    <td></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <div>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/usalabelexpress/"><img src="https://mcusercontent.com/e826d556957bbe51fc416e609/images/3d812f2a-b601-fbe3-97f7-03797e843efa.png"  alt="Facebook Icon" height="" width="8%" style="display: inline-block;" class="facebook responsiveImage"></a>
            <span><a href="https://www.usalabelexpress.com">www.usalabelexpress.com</a></span>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px; text-decoration:none;"> Cell: 330-432-6876 <br /> Email: jim@usalabelexpress.com </td>
</tr>
</table>

<!-- Bottom Text -->
<table role="presentation" border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;"><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/11206+Industrial+Pkwy+NW,+Bolivar,+OH+44612" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'sans-serif'; color: #001588; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;" class="address"> P.O. Box 518 ★ 11206 Industrial Parkway Bolivar, Ohio  44612 </a> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Office: 330-874-1001 ★ Fax: 330-874-9796 </td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it should look
[image]

This is how it shows on mobile

[image]

Comment: Please provide the relevant code. With this information you provided now it is impossible to help you.

Comment: @AztecCodes post has been updated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you avoid using max-width? A solution with that would be pretty easy.

Comment: @AztecCodes I'm not sure I entirely understand max-width or how to use it in my situation, but I am trying to research it now. I am also updating the post with images so you can see how the email is showing up on mobile vs how it should look. If you could give some more info on how I could best apply it in my situation that would be great. Thanks again for your help and patience, like I said I am new to this.

Comment: I am not an expert but [this](https://www.litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design) seems a good place to start.

Comment: "This is how it shows on mobile" - okay; **what is wrong with** this result, and **specifically how** should it be different?

Comment: @K8K media queries work perfectly in Gmail. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49701247/how-do-i-write-a-media-query-for-gmail